# g++ mistakes base constructor for field and ignores parameters to it

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, compiler-errors, g++

I have a base class, `class A<T>`, and a derrived class, `class B : public A<string>`.

`class A` has a constructor that takes an integer as its only parameter, and a standard copy constructor. It does not have a parameterless default constructor (not one that I've defined; I realize that the compiler may be creating one, which could be related to my problem).

The constructor for `class B` looks like this:

```
B()
: A(37)
{

}
```

The errors I'm getting are:

The compiler mistakes the base constructor call for a field initialization

```
fileB.h: In constructor ‘B::B()’:
fileB.h:25: error: class ‘B’ does not have any field named ‘A’
```

And

The compiler thinks a default (parameterless) base class constructor is being used, and suggests both of the non-default base class constructors...

```
// Where is it getting this? A() is never written explicitly
fileB.h:25: error: no matching function for call to ‘A<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::A()’
fileA.h:37: note: candidates are: A<T>::A(const A<T>&) [with T = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >]
```

...one of which should match what's being called.

```
// This one matches A(37), right?
fileA.h:24: note:                 A<T>::A(const int&) [with T = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >]
```

I believe this error is coming from the way my compiler was installed or configured, because when I compile my code on my computer, I don't get any errors, but I get the errors listed above when I scp everything to my school's computer and compile it there. I'm using g++ in both places, but obviously there's some difference somewhere. What is that difference, and where is the error coming from?

No conversion operator exists from A to int, nor vice-versa.

I'm using c++03 on both systems.

Here's a full code sample that reproduces the errors (again, only on the one system):

```
/*******************************
 * fileA.h
 ******************************/

template <class T>
class A
{
   int member;

  public:

   A(const int & m)
      : member(m)
   {
   }

   A(const A & copyFrom)
   {
      member = copyFrom.member;
   }
};


/*******************************
 * fileB.h
 ******************************/

#include <string>
#include "fileA.h"

using namespace std;

class B : public A<string>
{   
   B()
      : A(37)
   {

   }   
};
```

Comment: Where am I doing that?

Comment: `class B : public class A<string>` - did it really compile like that, with the word `class` before `A<string>`?

Comment: Grr. No, sorry, it's just `class B : public A<string>`. I'll edit it now.

Comment: It would probably make sense to provide a compilable code sample with reproducible error. It looks like GCC is supposed to compile your constructor as is (i.e. my original answer was incorrect).

Comment: Can't you post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Yes. I just whipped one up.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the default constructor for A is not generated by the compiler. If there is at least one defined constructor with parameters then the default constructor is not generated.

Secondly your problem comes from the fact that you don't specify the template parameter of A in the B constructor. You have to write:

```
B() : A<string>(37) {}
```

When you write A(37) the compiler looks for the non templated class A that doesn't exist.

The base classes are always constructed. As you don't construct A the compiler will do it for you calling the default constructor. As it doesn't exist it fails.

Comment: Using `A(37)` instead of `A<string>(37)` works perfectly on one system using g++, but not on another system using g++. I understand that `A<string>` is a more explicit type specifier, but why is that only needed on one system?

Comment: This should not work. But it is certainly implementation defined. One of your implementation may guess that you mean A<string> in B constructor because you derived B from A<string> in the class declaration.

Comment: What do you mean "implementation defined"? g++ is g++, is it not?

Comment: Perhaps you can give details on the two systems and the versions of g++ being used?

Comment: I was thinking of different versions. You could give us more informations. What are the systems are you talking about. And especially what are the versions of your compilers. It will be easier to help you.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. What information would be useful, and how can I get it?